# Controlling WS2812 with a non-PWM pin

Tags: pwm, raspberry-pi-os, ws2812

I was looking for a way to control WS2812 led without PWM pin (specifically I would use pin 4 (1-WIRE pin) to control WS2812). Is it possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not easily, not under Linux, the timing constraints are too tight (pulses of 0.4 µs or 0.8 µs in length).

You might be able to do it using DMA or SMI but I doubt you will find anyone to invest time in helping you to do so.